# Tamil font issue in Ubuntu touch phone (running Ubuntu 14.10 r15)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 14.10, language-support, nexus-4, translation

I have installed Ubuntu Touch 14.10 in my Nexus 4. Everything is working fine except rendering of Tamil fonts. I cannot read Tamil websites in any application like shorts and browser.

I tried installing the `language-pack-ta` and `language-pack-gnome-ta`. But I am getting errors saying `unable to locate these packages`. I have tried running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` first, but it's still not working. Can someone help me to install these language packs?

Comment: Sounds like you need e.g. the _ttf-tamil-fonts_ package rather than the language packs. But I'm not sure if you can easily install it yourself on Ubuntu Touch. Possibly you should file a bug where you ask that tamil fonts are included by default.

Comment: Thanks. I am managed to install ttf-tamil-fonts and now it is working properly.

Comment: Great! I wrote it as an answer as well, which you then can accept to show that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the *ttf-tamil-fonts* package rather than the language packs.